# d3 v4 zooming line without scaling up/down svg line elements

Tags: d3.js, zooming

I'm porting a D3 v3 graph widget that uses panning and zooming to v4 and got stuck on the zooming changes. The zooming API in v4 uses a different model where zooming is managed on the elements rather than a general zoom transform.

I have a lot of datapoints that get plotted on a timescale that initially intentionally clumps the datapoints very close to each other, and the user can use zooming to drill deeper into the data for more detail. In v3 when zooming in the svg line automatically adjusted with the new scale however in v4 when applying zoom scaling on the svg line I get an increases the thickness of the svg line elements rather than resolving more detail (and keeping the line thickness constant). I have no problems with scaling the x or y axis.

This behavior is expected with a scale function but not what I want. I've read the new API for zoom and can't work out what zoom function to use that would give me v3 behaviour where zooming in shows more detail in the line graph and doesn't scale up the line thickness.

In v3 D3 would zoom the svg line with the following in the zoom event handler, however this won't work in v4.

```
chart.select("#seriesLine" + i).attr("d", series[i].d3Line(series[i].data))
```

Its been a while since I wrote the original graphing widget so possibly I'm just not remembering how to setup D3 correctly, but I think I'm just not groking the new zoom function, and there are no similar zoom examples to learn from.

Any tips?

Comment: you just need vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" don't you?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I have to support IE and vector-effect isn't supported. I suppose I could inversely adjust the stroke width with the scale however this seems to be an obvious gap in the D3 v4 zoom function as zooming on line graphs is likely a common use case.

Comment: A problem with adjusting stroke-width as an inverse of the scale is that as I'm only scaling on the x axis (time series) its the horizontal line widths that gets expanded not the vertical lines - so I'm still stuck with an unworkable zoom.

Comment: Can you not just set a function that redefines the stroke width each time the zoom function is implemented - ie inside the .on('zoom', ...) function? This way you can manually reset each time zoom changes it.

Comment: No, as I'm scaling on the x-axis not y-axis (time-series chart) there is no way I know of just adjusting the horizontal svg width after using transform x axis scale in the zoom handler. This was seamless in D3 v3.